How to fix inaccessible VM
My VM (VirtualBox one) is on /media/hostname/UUID. This drive mounts every time on reeboot but my VM is inaccessible. In GUI have to access couple of times the drive... get into VM directory on it and in a short time VM becomes alive. From the terminal, it looks like this:
"inaccesible" {xxxxxxxxx-3e7a-4c0c-a17c-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
"nexxxxxx" {xxxxxxxxx-f48d-4776-bee3-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
... and after a while after accessing on GUI all folders as stated above:
"hcxxxxxx" {xxxxxxxxx-3e7a-4c0c-a17c-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
"nexxxxxx" {xxxxxxxxx-f48d-4776-bee3-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
Have accessed all folders, the drive, and gave all permission to all users... no luck.
How to fix it? ... or bypass it to run VM after the server reboots?...from the terminal?

To solve this issue I think I'll have to mount the second drive under Home directory and after that point VM to its new location inside Home directory.
